# Why does the Hodge-star of d$x$ equal d$y$ and not -d$y$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Wikipedia [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Formal_definition_for_k-vectors)

$$\star e_I = (-1)^{\sigma(I)} e_{\overline{I}}$$
where $\overline{I} = [n]\setminus I = \{\overline{i}_1< \cdots < \overline{i}_{n-k}\}$ and $\sigma(I)$ is the permutation $i_1 \dots i_k \overline{i}_1 \dots \overline{i}_{n-k}$. When taking $I = \{1\}$ and $n=2$, we would get $e_I = \text{d}x$, $\sigma(I) = (1\,\,2)$, $e_{\overline{I}} = \text{d}y$. The sign of $\sigma(I)$ is $-1$, so it would seem to me that

$$\star\text{d}x = -\text{d}y.$$
Wikipedia, however, [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Two_dimensions) $\star\text{d}x = \text{d}y$. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: That's a confusing way of writing it, but the sign is $+1$ because it's the sign of the identity permutation.

Comment: You want to think of $i_1\cdots i_k\overline{i}_1\cdots\overline{i}_{n-k}$ as an ordered list which is a permutation of the list $12\cdots n$ right? Then you're thinking of the list $12$ as a permutation of the list $12$, which is the identity permutation. It's wrong to put $12$ in parentheses and interpret it as a transposition.

Comment: You haven't really defined $\sigma(I)$ clearly. It is the permutation taking $12\dots n$ to $i_1\dots i_k\bar i_1\dots \bar i_{n-k}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin that does appear to be what runway44 suggests, and using that method it does in fact work out that the hodge star of dx would be dy. My problem was that I had been interpreting it as a cycle, which means that the mere fact that it has length $n$ would imply that its sign is $-1$.